# Application.Eval() Not working with expression

Tags: ms-access, vba

This line of code won't evaluate:

```vb
If(StrComp(Left("Campaign", 5), "IMS :") = 0
```

I'm using it like this:

```vb
strHolder = "If(StrComp(Left("Campaign", 5), "IMS :") = 0"
myVar = Application.Eval(strHolder)
```

This is the error I'm receiving:

> ```vb
> Run-time error '2425':
>
> The expression you entered has a function name that Microsoft Access can't find.
> ```

I'm guessing that `Application.Eval` can't read either the `If` , `StrComp` , or `Left`

Not sure what to do here, and I can't find the much in-depth info on the `Eval` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This line of code won't evaluate:
>
> ```
> If(StrComp(Left("Campaign", 5), "IMS :") = 0
> ```

And it wouldn't compile either due to unbalanced parentheses and `If` without `Then`.

There should also be a compile error at this line ...

```vb
strHolder = "If(StrComp(Left("Campaign", 5), "IMS :") = 0"
```

If you want something like this Immediate window example ...

```vb
? StrComp(Left("Campaign", 5), "IMS :") = 0
False
```

... then double up the `"` characters within the string which you submit to `Eval()` ...

```vb
strHolder = "StrComp(Left(""Campaign"", 5), ""IMS :"") = 0"
? strHolder
StrComp(Left("Campaign", 5), "IMS :") = 0
myVar = Application.Eval(strHolder)
? myVar
 0
? CBool(myVar)
False
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So.. I've played with this for a while now.  You were correct about several syntax errors, but not all.  1.  Doubling the quotes did not work - not sure why, but in the end I did need single quotes.  2. Stripping the if statement and evaluating to a bool variable was the key to success(pretty much what you did here).  Is there a syntax to correctly evaluate an entire IF statement from string?

Comment: Not sure.  Do you have an example of an entire `If` statement which you would want `Eval()` to evaluate?

Comment: `If(StrComp(Left("Campaign", 5), "IMS :") Then Return someValue`  Not sure how to syntax this.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible that way.  `Eval()` is not equipped to deal with the type of expression you want to feed it --- that is like a code block as a single line --- Access complains it can't find the name 'If' with any similar attempts I've tried.  Maybe you can use `IIf()` to get what you want: `IIf(Eval("expression"), "case when True", "whatever when False")` ... but with an "expression" which `Eval()` can handle.